How to switch default pdf viewer?
On Ubuntu 22.04 i can right click on a PDF > properties > Open with
AND in there i could select the default app to open a PDF, so next time i just have to double click. But on Ubuntu 24.04 i don't have that option to switch the default PDF viewer.
Does anyone knows how to change the default PDF Viewer on 24.04?

I can't say about 24.04 since I just upgraded to 24.10 but I imagine it would be the same...

open files(nautilus)
right click on pdf file
choose 'Open With..' (second from the top)
Select the program you want to open it with eg: Firefox
At the bottom of the pop up window, enable the 'Always use for this file type' option
then select 'Open' at the top of the pop up window.

The change will then be permanent.
